# Is a compact subset of a topological group G/N closed if G is hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, quotient-spaces, locally-compact-groups

I just used this hypothesis when I was proving a theorem.But I was not sure if this hypothesis is correct.

Comment: Note that the statement is definitely false for *monoids*: homeomorphically embed $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ into $(\mathbb{R}, \times)$ as the interval $(0, \infty)$.

Comment: Yes.If G is hausdorff,and if K is a compact subset of G/N,is K closed?@NoahSchweber

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** This is a response to the original question:

> If $G$ is a Hausdorff topological group and $N$ is a normal subgroup is the quotient map $G\to G/N$ always a closed map?

Assuming $G$ is Hausdorff, one necessary condition for the quotient map $q\colon G \to G/N$ to be closed is that $N$ is closed in $G$. Otherwise $q^{-1}(q(\{1\})) = N$ isn't a closed set, which means that $q(\{1\})$ isn't closed in $G/N$.

For example, the quotient map $q\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ isn't closed since $q^{-1}(q(\{0\})) = \mathbb{Q}$ isn't a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$.

However, there are lots of examples where $N$ is closed in $G$ but the quotient map is not closed.  For example, if $G = \mathbb{R}^2$ and $N=\{0\}\times\mathbb{R}$, then the quotient map $G\to G/N$ is essentially the projection of $\mathbb{R}^2$ onto its first factor.  This is not a closed map since, for example, the set
$$
\{(x,\tan x) \mid -\pi/2<x<\pi/2\}
$$
is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but its projection onto the first factor is not.

The quotient map is always closed if $G$ is compact and $G/N$ is Hausdorff, since every map from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a closed map.  It follows that the quotient map is closed whenever $G$ is compact Hausdorff and $N$ is closed, since then it follows that $G/N$ is Hausdorff (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9022/quotient-of-a-hausdorff-topological-group-by-a-closed-subgroup)).

Comment: I just changed my question,you may edit your answer if you wish@JimBelk

Comment: @Meelod For future reference, it's usually not considered polite on this site to change your question after it's been answered.  It's better to leave the original as it is and then start a new question.

Comment: I am new in here,but I won`t change my question again...

Comment: @Meelod The answer to your new question is no, by the way.  For example, one-point sets are compact but not closed in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @Meelod Isn't $A=\{0\}$, $G = \mathbb{R}$, and $N=\mathbb{Q}$ a counterexample?

Comment: yes.now I have no question...thanks for helping me.In fact I had an exam and I was trying to justify my wrong hypothesis.thanks @JimBelk